# Windows Chrome touch events working, but not mouse click-drag

Tags: google-chrome, touch, ionic-framework, windows-8.1

I have an Ionic app that's being brought over for use as a desktop web application.  That means it's running itself in browsers like FireFox, IE, Chrome... etc

One thing I've noticed is, on Windows Chrome I can scroll certain elements ONLY when using the touch screen.  I cannot, for instance, click and drag the elements (which I can do just fine in OSX)

here's an oversimplification of one such element's html

```
<ion-content ...>
   <div class="someclassyClasses ..." ...>
       <ion-scroll direction="y" has-bouncing="false" ...>
            <ion-list ...>
                <div ng-repeat="group in groups" ...>
```

Environment is

```
Windows 8.1
Chrome 44.x
HP Touch Envy Laptop
```

Comment: same issue here. Not a fix yet, but this person was able to find a workaround. http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problems-getting-scroll-events-in-chrome-on-a-touchscreen-laptop/33399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems it was a bug.. trying to use ionic apps on desktop too soon